# Showing a UFD which is not a PID must have a nonprincipal maximal ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Given that $R$ is a UFD which is not a PID, I want to show that $R$ must have a nonprincipal maximal ideal.

I tried several methods, including Zorn's lemma but didn't get anywhere. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: By Zorn, every proper ideal is contained in a maximal one. I'd try using that fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $R$ be a UFD in which each maximal ideal is principal, and let $I$ be a nonzero ideal of $R$.  Let $(x)$ be the greatest common divisor of all the nonzero elements of $I$, so $I = (x)J$, where $J$ is an ideal which is contained in no proper principal ideal.  But then by our assumption $J$ is contained in no maximal ideal, so $J = R$ and $I = (x)$.

**Added**: Let me address why gcds of arbitrary sets of elements exist in a UFD.  Let $R$ be a UFD and let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of nonzero principal prime ideals of $R$, so that for all nonzero $x \in R$, $x = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}} p^{n_p(x)}$, where each $n_p(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ and all but finitely many are zero.  For any subset $S = (x_s)$ of nonzero elements of $R$, the greatest common divisor of the elements of $S$ is $\prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}} p^{\min_{s \in S} n_p(x_s)}$: this exists!  (In fact there is a finite subset $T \subset S$ such that $\operatorname{gcd}(S) = \operatorname{gcd}(T)$.)

Comment: I acknowledge http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math/2008-10/msg03739.html.

Comment: Is it possible to find the gcd of infinitely many elements?

Comment: @ehsanmo: in the present case $I$ is contained in only finitely many principal prime ideals, because $R$ is a UFD. Thus the gcd exists.

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**. Let $R$ be a *non-Noetherian* UFD where all of its maximal ideals are principal, then it is a PID.

Assume the contrary and let $I$ be an ideal which is maximal w.r.t being non-principal, then $I$ is a prime ideal (Look at the [Theorem 1.4.](http://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emreyes/oka1.pdf) for more detail.) By assumption, $I$ cannot be maximal, thus there is a maximal ideal $m=(x)$ containing $I$ properly (note that $x$ is an irreducible element.) Now, $m \subseteq I+m \subseteq R.$

If $m=I+m,$ based on assumption, any prime ideal contains a prime element (See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Equivalent_conditions_for_a_ring_to_be_a_UFD)). Let $i \in I$ be a prime element, then $xt=i+xr$ for some $t,r \in R,$ then $i=x(t-r).$ Obviously, $i$ cannot divide $x$ so $t-r=is$ for some $s \in R.$ Therefore, $i=x(t-r)=xis$ implying that $x$ is a unit which a contradiction.

If $I+m=R$ i.e. $is+xr=1$ for $i \in I,$ and $s,r \in R.$ Now, $i \in (x),$ or $i=xt$ for some $t \in R.$ Thus, $x(ts+r)=1$ implying that $x$ is a unit element, which is again a contradiction. Hence such an $I$ does not exist and we're done.

**Case 2**. Let $R$ be a *Noetherian* UFD where all of its maximal ideals are principal, then it is a PID.

Assume not, and let $I$ be the prime ideal above contained in a principal maximal ideal $m=(x)$ Since $R$ is a Noetherian UFD then any height one prime ideal is principal, therefore, $ht(I) \geq 2$ implying that $ht(m) \geq 3,$ hence is a contradiction, by [Krull's principal ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem).

*Addendum*:

You can see another short proof below by Pete L. Clark. In fact, I was not aware of the fact that Kaplansky's theorem (as mentioned, [15.1 here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)) holds for all domains.

Comment: I think you have a very simple proof slightly hidden in here.  Namely, suppose $R$ is a UFD with all maximal ideals principal.  If $R$ is not a PID there is a nonprincipal prime $\mathfrak{p}$ contained in a principal maximal ideal $(x)$.  By Kaplansky's Theorem, $\mathfrak{p}$ contains a nonzero prime element $y$.  Thus $x \mid y$ but $x$ and $y$ are prime, so $(x) = (y)$ and $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{m}$ is principal, contradiction.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Yes, indeed, for the case 1.

Comment: @ehsanmmo: But your Case 1 argument doesn't use that $R$ is *not* Noetherian...it just doesn't require that $R$ is Noetherian.  So there is no need for Case 2.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: As far as I know, Kaplansky's theorem holds for Non-Noetherain rings.Here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Equivalent_conditions_for_a_ring_to_be_a_UFD

Comment: @ehsanmno: Ah, I see -- you are going by the wikipedia article.  But in fact Kaplansky's theorem holds for all domains: see e.g. $\S 15.1$ of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf.  (Or see Kaplansky's book!)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark:Now, I see. Good to know that, thanks!

Comment: $@$ehsanmo: I put this result in my commutative algebra notes (Section 16).  The proof that emerged from my comments on your answer is the one given in the text.  The one in my answer is given as an exercise.